# Why does the key for ^, ~ and ¨ not work in IntelliJ Idea on Ubuntu?

Tags: intellij

On my keyboard (Nordic layout) the key just left of Return key is used for symbols ", ^ and ~. 
This key works perfectly in all applications on Ubuntu but for some reason this button does not do anything at all in IntelliJ Idea.

What could be the problem?

Comment: That's cause it's mapped differently in IntelliJ check the key mapping in IntelliJ and change what you don't like

Comment: No, I don't think so. Going into the keymap and searching for the button results in nothing. There is nothing bound to that button. Is it called Dead Diaresis or something like that. So, something else is blocking it...